# svnant command to copy files from an ssh repository to a sever?

Tags: svn, ant, repository, svnant

Hi is there anybody who knows how to write the copy command for **svn-ant** or just svn to copy files from an **ssh repository**(svn+ssh://username@10.10.10.10/media/repository/files) to a **server folder** (var/httdocs/files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command.

The command line would look like this:

```
svn export svn+ssh://username@10.10.10.10/media/repository/files /var/httdocs/files
```

The [svnant equivalent](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html#export) would look like this:

```
<svn>
    <export srcUrl="svn+ssh://username@10.10.10.10/media/repository/files"
            destPath="/var/httdocs/files" />
</svn>
```