# Exporting folders from svn using ant script

Tags: svn, ant

I am facing a situation while working with svn repository.I want to export multiple folders from svn to my workspace in C drive using ANT script but not able to configure how to do it.Can anyone please help me out as to what ant script should i write to export folders from svn to local workspace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) library to do so. Also there are a few answers in stackoverflow, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400893/how-to-checkout-from-svn-with-an-ant-task) (usage of svnant) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495253/svnant-command-to-copy-files-from-an-ssh-repository-to-a-sever) (svnant export command).

Comment: I tried doing by that, but I am not able to export multiple folders.Suppose my build.xml contains 2 export statements, then it only executes and exports the first statement.I am not able to export the second folder.

Comment: post the relevant parts of your build.xml so that we can look at it?

Comment: The following are the 2 export statements I am using:                                                           <export  srcUrl="svn/repos/eai_sourcecode/trunk/EAI_Code/A1" destPath="C:\BuildWorkSpace\test project" revision="HEAD" />
                

<export  srcUrl="svn/repos/eai_sourcecode/trunk/EAI_Code/A2" destPath="C:\BuildWorkSpace\test project" revision="HEAD" />. I am exportiing 2 folders A1 and A2 but when i execute the ant script in cmd, only the first folder is retrieved in my local workspace.I want to export both folders from SVN to local workspace.Appreciate your help.